# How can I display articles based on "Tags" or "Keywords" in Sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-keywords, tags

I am working on a task where we want to display articles in a carousel based on the tags associated with them. Can I do it in Sharepoint? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this in SharePoint Online is starting with a [modern team site](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-team-site-in-sharepoint-online-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d) or [communication site](https://support.office.com/article/what-is-a-sharepoint-communication-site-94a33429-e580-45c3-a090-5512a8070732). You can set properties on the pages that can be used to filter your web part shown in the carousel layout.

Once you have modern pages, there are only two steps.

1. Add the Highlighted content web part to [a modern page](https://support.office.com/article/add-a-page-to-a-site-b3d46deb-27a6-4b1e-87b8-df851e503dec) and chose
   a filter.
2. Set the layout to Carousel.

Today, you can use managed properties with the highlighted content web part. [By the end of July](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Structure-your-intranet-page-metadata-coming-to-SharePoint-in/ba-p/212555) you should be able to use any property of the page.

**Reference**

- [Use the Highlighted content web part](https://support.office.com/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd), support.office.com
- [Add a page to a site](https://support.office.com/article/add-a-page-to-a-site-b3d46deb-27a6-4b1e-87b8-df851e503dec), support.office.com
- [Structure your intranet – page metadata coming to SharePoint in Office 36](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Structure-your-intranet-page-metadata-coming-to-SharePoint-in/ba-p/212555)5, techcommunity.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

That is a pretty common request, just goggle for Sharepoint News Rotator. However the answer is depends on the format of your articles. Are you using publishing pages, blog post or the modern news?